# Transfer text from one file to another

Tags: python

I have a problem with transferring the dist parameter from the input file to the result file to the same place where it was located in the input file
My code is:

```
import requests
import json
import time

with open("query4.txt", "rt") as file:
        data_file = file.read()

with open("result.txt", "w") as f_o:
    for line in data_file.split("\n"):
            for i in range(1):
                    drX, drY, fromX, fromY, dist = line.split(",")

                    url = "https://api.openrouteservice.org/directions?"
                    params = [
                            ["api_key", "my_api_key"],
                            ["coordinates", "%s,%s|%s,%s" % (drY, drX, fromY, fromX)],
                            ["profile", "driving-car"]
                    ]
                    headers = {
                            "Accept": "application/json, application/geo+json,"
                                      "application/gpx+xml, img/png; charset=utf-8"}
                    responce = requests.get(url=url, params=params, headers=headers)
                    print(responce.url)
                    # print(responce.text)
                    result = json.loads(responce.text)
                    print(result)
                    for rows in result["routes"]:
                            print(rows["summary"]["distance"], file=f_o)  # depending on how do you want the result
                            # print(result["routes"])
                            time.sleep(0)
```

Input sample:

```
48.94205856,38.48511505,48.94167600,38.49207300,511
46.54586411,30.64417267,46.53338808,30.65455914,1599
50.06436157,31.44526100,50.07415641,31.45929694,1482
50.35911942,30.94097710,50.33576900,30.95166500,2706
50.35837936,30.94162369,50.33576900,30.95166500,2614
```

As the output now i have a distance from summary json like

```
123.2
122.5
221
312.7
212
```

I want to get this

```
123.2 125
122.5 122
221 340
312.7 300
212 220
```

I used this, but it seems not to work:

```
with open("query4.txt") as f:
    input_file = f.read()
    with open("result.txt", "w") as f1:
        for line in input_file.split("\n"):
            for line in f:
                dX, dY, fX, fY, dst = line.split(",")
                if "dst" in line:
                    f1.write(line)
```

Comment: What the point about doing `for i in range(1)`?

Comment: the point was to give how many times each row should be done, it's about ```time.sleep()``` If range is 5 - each row from the file is going to be requested 5 times.

Comment: I don't get why you would process each row multiple times, but that's not the problem. More important, what is supposed to be the second numbers in your expected output? It seems that you want to print distances between coordinates using an api, what's wrong with the result you get?

Comment: I have a distances from my local ORS, and it represented as the last numbers after the coordinates in the sample i've given above. This should be statistics between 2 ors, mine (local ors) and ors itself.

Comment: I'm getting distances between coordinates, but i want to add MY distances which i got a month ago or a year ago e.t.c to compare their diference

Comment: so the point is to put in the result file the distances from input file and make them stand at the same positions as in the input file

Comment: @olinox14 would you help me please with this one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply have to add the `dist` variable to the print command. Also, there are a few improvements that could bring to your code:

```
import requests
import json

url = "https://api.openrouteservice.org/directions?"

headers = {"Accept": "application/json, application/geo+json, application/gpx+xml, img/png; charset=utf-8"}

with open("query4.txt", "rt") as f_i, open("result.txt", "w") as f_o:

    for line in f_i:
        drX, drY, fromX, fromY, file_dist = line.split(",")

        params = [
                ["api_key", "my_api_key"],
                ["coordinates", "%s,%s|%s,%s" % (drY, drX, fromY, fromX)],
                ["profile", "driving-car"]
        ]

        response = requests.get(url=url, params=params, headers=headers)
        result = json.loads(response.text)

        for rows in result["routes"]:
            f_o.write("{from_api} - {from_file}\n".format(from_api = rows["summary"]["distance"], from_file = file_dist) )
```

> If you wonder about the formatting part, take a look there: https://realpython.com/python-string-formatting

Comment: Thank you for the code. I'm getting an error KeyError: 'routes'
And i'm trying to find the mistake. But i see nothing.

Comment: Your `f_o.write` statement is not using an `f` string. Even if it were, I you need to assign values to from_api and from_file prior to the write call, not as arguments to that call.

Comment: Could you check the content of the `response` object and the `result` dict by printing them?

Comment: @RonaldAaronson Damn you're right, I forgot the `format` method! My mistake, fixed. But I preferred to use format instead of an f-string here, because the use of keywords made it more readable.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Lotarc/PycharmProjects/Request/Request.py", line 24, in <module>
<Response [200]>
    f_o.write("{from_api} - {from_file}\n", from_api = rows["summary"]["distance"], from_file = file_dist)
TypeError: write() takes no keyword arguments
I've got an output but only from one. and now it tells me this

Comment: Yes, but you gave a link to f-strings.

Comment: Yeeeahh guys, THANK YOU VERY MUCH. It's doing so well. I really appreciate your help. Thank you!

Comment: @RonaldAaronson it's a full formatting tuto, it happened that the link pointed to the f-string paragraph... Fixed.